# How to use Trello JS API to create a card

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, trello

I've been trying to utilize the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/index.html) via JSFiddle and haven't been able to get it to work (I have very limited JS/JSON knowledge). I need to create a card under a specific list, using the API.

```
function PostStuff()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
    Trello.authorize({
    interactive: true,
    type: "popup",
    expiration: "never",
    name: "surveyrequest",
    persist: "true",
    success: function() { onAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
    error: function() { onFailedAuthorization(); },
    scope: { read: true, write: true}
});

function onAuthorizeSuccessful() {    
    Trello.post("cards", { name: "Card created for test", desc: "this is a test",  idList: "........", due: null, urlSource: null});
        }
    });
}
```

I have JQuery and the Trello API included. I blanked out the idList in the code for security purposes. I confirmed that the code does execute the onAuthorizeSuccessful() function.

How can I modify this to create a Trello card?

Comment: You might want to try adding an error handler to the `Trello.post` so you can figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Auth() {    
   Trello.authorize({
                type: 'popup',
                name: 'your app name',
                scope: {
                    read: true,
                    write: true },
                expiration: '30days',
                success: authenticationSuccess,
                error: authenticationFailure
            });
    var authenticationSuccess = function(data){ /*your function stuff*/};
    var authenticationFailure = function(data){ /*your function stuff*/};

}
```

this code works for me. i get function Auth() triggered on button click.

Also, you might have some issues with tokens which are expired, so `Trello.deauthorize();` could be used on create new card failure function (it all depends on create new card error message).

regarding the create a new card...

```
var newCard = 
          {name: jQuery('input#tc_title').val(), 
          desc: jQuery('textarea#tc_desc').val(),
          pos: "top", 
          idList: trello_list_id_var
          };

Trello.post('/cards/', newCard, success, error);

var success = function(data){ /*..............*/}
var error= function(data){ /*..............*/}
```

in success/error functions you are able to check the error data

EDIT:
also i think that `Trello.post("cards" ...` should be replaced with `Trello.post("/cards/" ...` that might be the problem...